# Can't Enable LDAP on WAS 8.5.5

Tags: ldap, websphere, websphere-8

I have an issue, I want to enable LDAP on my WAS, like in this [article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_4.0.0/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_instl_config_ldap_on_was.html).

But in step number 4 (`Test Connection`), I always get this error message:

> ErrorSECJ7340E: Exception raised trying to connect to LDAP server:
>   NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DD, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1772]

I thought that, I must binding the connection or something related about the connection, but I don't know exactly.

Is there any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

This article talks about standalone ldap configuration. You should rather use LDAP in federated registry. Please follow this link for configuration - [Configuring a single LDAP repository under Federated repositories](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twim_ldap_filebased.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-8-2-33-2-1-3-10&lang=en)

Based on the error you have, looks like your LDAP requires authenticated user. You need to provide bind user and bind user password.

See also:

- [LDAP repository settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twim_ldap_settings.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-8-2-33-2-1-3-12&lang=en)